# java.lang.illegalargumentexception unrecognized content type

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Getting java.lang.illegalargumentexception unrecognized content type when showing dialog.

I'm writing some test application which implements some show cases in primefaces. In particular, I want to implement a (primefaces) data table, where I can open a dialog and add travel costs on button click. This worked fine with Glassfish server 5.0.1 (including Mojarra 2.3.2 and Primefaces 5.0), but I get the exception above with Glassfish server 5.1 (including Mojarra 2.3.9 and Primefaces 6.1). Anyhow, the list of costs in the backing bean maintains the correct values, only the table is not getting updating. What may be wrong? 
Please ignore some style constants in the bean, it's just a test project.

contentCreateExpense.xhtml:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <body>
    <ui:composition>
        <h:form>
            <div>
                <h:outputLabel value="Neue Abrechnung erstellen" styleClass="caption-label-style"/>
                <br/>
            </div>

            <div>
                <p:outputLabel value="Name der Abrechnung: "/>
                <p:inputText value="#{createExpenseController.expenseName}">
                    <f:ajax/>
                </p:inputText>
                <br/>
            </div>

            <p:panel header="Details Ihrer Dienstreise">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                    <p:outputLabel for="country" value="Land: "/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="country" value="#{createExpenseController.country}">
                        <p:ajax listener="#{createExpenseController.onCountryChange}" update="city" />
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Waehlen Sie ein Land aus" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{createExpenseController.countries}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel for="city" value="Stadt: "/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="city" value="#{createExpenseController.city}" style="#{createExpenseController.dropdownStyle}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Waehlen Sie eine Stadt aus" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{createExpenseController.cities}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                    <p:outputLabel for="customer" value="Kunde: "/>
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="customer" value="#{createExpenseController.customer}" style="#{createExpenseController.dropdownStyle}">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Waehlen Sie einen Kunden aus" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                        <f:selectItems value="#{createExpenseController.customers}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                </h:panelGrid>

                <p:separator />

                <h:panelGroup id="dataTableGroup">
                    <p:dataTable id="costTable"
                                 var="c"
                                 value="#{createExpenseController.costs}"
                                 emptyMessage="Keine Kosten vorhanden">
                        <p:column id="positionColumn" headerText="Belegart" style="#{createExpenseController.tableStyle}">
                            <p:outputLabel id="position" value="#{c.type}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column id="costsHeader" headerText="Kosten" style="#{createExpenseController.tableStyle}">
                            <p:outputLabel id="cost" value="#{c.cost}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column id="actionHeader" headerText="Aktion" style="#{createExpenseController.tableStyle}">
                            <p:commandLink
                                id="deleteButton"
                                update="costTable"
                                value="Position loeschen"
                                process="@this"
                                actionListener="#{createExpenseController.removeCost(c)}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:panelGroup>                

                <p:commandButton onclick="PF('costDialog').show();" value="Weitere Position hinzufuegen" update="costTable"/>
            </p:panel>
            <p:commandLink actionListener="#{createExpenseController.forwardMyExpensesActionListener()}" value="Abrechnung erstellen"/>
        </h:form>
        <h:form>
            <p:dialog header="Beleg hinzufuegen" widgetVar="costDialog" height="200" width="400" resizable="false">
                <p:panel>
                    <h:panelGrid id="costPanel" columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                        <p:outputLabel value="Belegart: "/>
                        <p:inputText id="typeInput" value="#{createExpenseController.currentType}" 
                                     required="true" requiredMessage="Geben Sie bitte eine Belegart an."/>
                        <p:outputLabel value="Kosten: "/>
                        <p:inputText id="costInput" value="#{createExpenseController.currentCost}" 
                                     validator="#{createExpenseController.validateBigDecimal}" required="true"
                                     requiredMessage="Geben Sie bitte die Kosten an." />
                        <p:message id="msgIdType" for="typeInput" style="#{createExpenseController.labelStyle}" />
                        <p:message id="msgIdCost" for="costInput" style="#{createExpenseController.labelStyle}" />
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
                <p:commandButton value="Kosten hinzufuegen" actionListener="#{createExpenseController.addCost()}" 
                                 oncomplete="if(!args.validationFailed) PF('costDialog').hide();" update=":#{p:component('costTable')} typeInput costInput"/>
            </p:dialog>  
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

CreateExpenseController.java:

```html
package com.testmanagement.controller;

import com.testmanagement.dto.Cost;
import com.testmanagement.dto.LastLoginDto;
import com.testmanagement.service.LastLoginService;
import com.testmanagement.util.URLParams;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.component.UIInput;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CreateExpenseController implements Serializable {

    private static final String CAPTION_LABEL_STYLE = "margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #3399ff; background-color: white; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; background: white; font-size: 18px;";
    private static final String LABEL_STYLE = "margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #3399ff; background-color: white; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; background: white;";
    private static final String BUTTON_STYLE = "margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; color: #3399ff; background-color: white; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; background: white;";
    private static final String MENU_STYLE = "color: #3399ff; background-color: white; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; background: white;";
    private static final String DROPDOWN_STYLE = "margin-right: 10px; margin-left: 10px; width: 200px; color: #3399ff; background-color: white; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; background: white;";
    private static final String TABLE_STYLE = "color: #3399ff; background-color: white; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12px; background: white;";

    private String text;
    private String expenseName;
    private Date expenseDate;

    private List<Cost> costs;
    private BigDecimal sum;
    private String currentType = "";
    private String currentCost = "";

    private Map<String, Map<String, String>> data = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String customer;
    private Map<String, String> countries;
    private Map<String, String> cities;
    private Map<String, String> customers;

    @Inject
    private ParamTransportBean paramTransportBean;

    @Inject
    private LastLoginService lastLoginService;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            lastLoginService.save(new LastLoginDto(null, "manager", new Date()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        countries = new HashMap<String, String>();
        countries.put("USA", "USA");
        countries.put("Deutschland", "Deutschland");
        countries.put("Brasilien", "Brasilien");

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("New York", "New York");
        map.put("San Francisco", "San Francisco");
        map.put("Denver", "Denver");
        data.put("USA", map);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Berlin", "Berlin");
        map.put("Muenchen", "Muenchen");
        map.put("Frankfurt", "Frankfurt");
        data.put("Deutschland", map);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("Sao Paulo", "Sao Paulo");
        map.put("Rio de Janerio", "Rio de Janerio");
        map.put("Salvador", "Salvador");
        data.put("Brasilien", map);

        customers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        customers.put("SAP", "SAP");
        customers.put("Microsoft", "Microsoft");
        customers.put("IBM", "IBM");

        costs = new ArrayList<Cost>();
        sum = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }

    public String getCaptionLabelStyle() {
        return CAPTION_LABEL_STYLE;
    }

    public String getLabelStyle() {
        return LABEL_STYLE;
    }

    public String getButtonStyle() {
        return BUTTON_STYLE;
    }

    public String getMenuStyle() {
        return MENU_STYLE;
    }

    public String getDropdownStyle() {
        return DROPDOWN_STYLE;
    }

    public String getTableStyle() {
        return TABLE_STYLE;
    }

    public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(String customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCountries() {
        return countries;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCities() {
        return cities;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getCustomers() {
        return customers;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public String getExpenseName() {
        return expenseName;
    }

    public void setExpenseName(String expenseName) {
        this.expenseName = expenseName;
    }

    public Date getExpenseDate() {
        return expenseDate;
    }

    public void setExpenseDate(Date expenseDate) {
        this.expenseDate = expenseDate;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public List<Cost> getCosts() {
        return costs;
    }

    public void setCosts(List<Cost> costs) {
        this.costs = costs;
    }

    public BigDecimal getSum() {
        return sum;
    }

    public String getCurrentType() {
        return currentType;
    }

    public void setCurrentType(String currentType) {
        this.currentType = currentType;
    }

    public String getCurrentCost() {
        return currentCost;
    }

    public void setCurrentCost(String currentCost) {
        this.currentCost = currentCost;
    }

    public int getNumberOfCosts() {
        return costs.size();
    }

    public void addCost() {
        BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal(currentCost);
        costs.add(new Cost(currentType, c));
        sum = sum.add(c);
        currentType = null;
        currentCost = null;
    }

    public void removeCost(Cost c) {
        costs.remove(c);
        sum = sum.subtract(c.getCost());
    }

    public int indexOf(BigDecimal c) {
        return costs.indexOf(c);
    }

    public void validateBigDecimal(FacesContext context, UIComponent comp, Object value) {
        String stringValue = (String) value;
        BigDecimal c;
        try {
            c = new BigDecimal(stringValue);
            if (c.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0) {
                ((UIInput) comp).setValid(false);
                FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("msgIdCost", "Geben Sie bitte eine positive Zahl ein.");
                context.addMessage(comp.getClientId(context), message);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ((UIInput) comp).setValid(false);
            FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("msgIdCost", "Geben Sie bitte eine gueltige Zahl ein.");
            context.addMessage(comp.getClientId(context), message);
        }
    }

    public void onCountryChange() {
        if (country != null && !country.equals("")) {
            cities = data.get(country);
        } else {
            cities = new HashMap<String, String>();
        }
    }

    public void forwardMyExpensesActionListener() {
        URLParams urlParams = new URLParams();
        String conversationId = paramTransportBean.initializeConversation();
        paramTransportBean.setExpenseName(expenseName);
        paramTransportBean.setCountry(country);
        paramTransportBean.setCity(city);
        paramTransportBean.setCustomer(customer);
        paramTransportBean.setCosts(costs);
        paramTransportBean.setSum(sum);
        urlParams.appendParameter("cid", conversationId);
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        String url = "myExpensesClient.xhtml" + urlParams.getParams();
        try {
            externalContext.redirect(url);
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

The expected result is, that my data table gets updated after adding a travel cost in in dialog. However, I get the following exception:

```html
Severe:   Error Rendering View[/createExpenseClient.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unerkannter Inhaltstyp
 at com.sun.faces.renderkit.RenderKitImpl.createResponseWriter(RenderKitImpl.java:259)
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1125)
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:415)
 at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:170)
 at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
 at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
 at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1540)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:119)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:611)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:550)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:75)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:114)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:199)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:439)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:182)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:156)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:218)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:260)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:177)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:109)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:88)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:53)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:515)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:89)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:94)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:33)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:114)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:569)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:549)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Hi, please start by learning how to create a [mcve] (see also http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) like requested in [ask]
. There is way to much code that is not relevant and that makes it hard for us to find a cause. By creating a [mcve] you narrow down the problem a lot!

Comment: It looks like you are having an old jsf-impl-1.2 on your class path.  Mojarra 2.3.9 does not throw IllegalArgumentException at line 259 of RenderKitImpl. Please also inspect what the content of the `Accept` header is within the request sent to the server.